# WpBingo Core Plugin breaking my Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a site locally for a client. WpBingo was already installed on the site, I'm just making little style revisions. I have not edited anything in the plugin file. Last night the site was working fine, this morning it's giving me this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array in /Users/hannahleavitt/Local Sites/costa-pickleball/app/public/wp-content/plugins/wpbingo/function.php on line 293

I can't get into the Dashboard or the site. I have already tried deleting the plugin and reinstalling it. When I delete it the site works, but because so much of the site is based on it everything looks weird and the formatting is really messed up. When I reinstall and activate it it breaks immediately and gives me that error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here (but at line 269).
Quick fix (awaiting official update) :

in /wp-content/plugins/wpbingo/function.php, replace:

```
if (is_array( $function) && is_a( $function['function'][0], $class ) && $method === $function['function'][1]) {
```

with

```
if (is_array( $function) && is_array($function['function']) && is_a( $function['function'][0], $class ) && $method === $function['function'][1]) {
```